# How should I print out the position of the first occurrence of a specific letter in a String?

Tags: java

Say my string is as follows

String str = "What is up tod?";

I want to use an accessor method to print out the position of the first occurrence of the letter "t". What is an efficient use of code to use? I also want to ensure that it doesn't try to tell me the occurrence of the second "t". Please keep in mind I am searching for how to do this in Java.

Any help or link to similar question is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `String.indexOf` ? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, use [`String.indexOf(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) like

```
String str = "What is up tod?";
System.out.println(str.indexOf('t'));
```

Which outputs the first match

```
3
```

Alternatively, iterate the characters of the `String` from left to right checking for `'t'`; if you find it, print the index and terminate the loop. Like,

```
String str = "What is up tod?";
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) == 't') {
        System.out.println(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That works for what I am attempting to use this for thank you, I kept getting redirected to useful links however a bit more complicated than I needed.